# Detecting a partially obscured rectangle in image with openCV

Tags: opencv, tracking, detection

I am working on a project and I ran into a situation. I want to **detect a rectangle object (a black keyboard) in an IR image**. The background is pretty clean so it's not really a hard problem, I used simple **threshold** and **minAreaRect** in OpenCV to solve it.
[Easy case of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL6Es.png)

But I also want the program to track this object when I **use my hand to move it** (yes, in real time). And my hand will cover a small part of the object like this case. [Tricky case of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARSHs.png)

My initial thought is to learn the object size in the easy case, and for the hard case, try to match my "learned rectangle" to cover as many white pixels as possible.

Anyone has a better solution, maybe a feature-based approach? I don't know if using features can improve the situation because object is mostly black in these IR images.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using morphological operations like dilation and erosion (Opencv has implementations for these) on the thresholded image. Once you get that, you could try some corner detection/contour detection or line detectors(in opencv contrib module) to understand the shape of the object.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using morphological operations and it seemed to work.

Comment: @duy_sau_rom If you found the answer useful, and it solved your problem, please consider upvoting and marking the answer as 'accepted'

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow and need a little bit more reputation to upvote. I will come back and upvote for you later. :')

Answer (score 1):

Your "tricky" case is still fairly simple, can be solved with dilate/erode (as mentioned by Shawn Mathew) and then the same `minAreaRect`. Here, on the right is your thresholded image after erosion and dilation with a 5x5 kernel, `minAreaRect` finds a rotated rectangle for it, drawn over the original thresholded image on the left:

[image]

Are you interested in more complicated cases, for example, where you hand covers one of the short edges of the keyboard entirely?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I guess that case is pretty tough and can't be solved easily without knowing the original size of the keyboard right?

Comment: I don't think it can be solved at all without knowing the original size, but if you know not even the size, but the long/short side ratio, it becomes somewhat simple: minAreaRect gives you a shortened version of rectangle, you estimate, which one of the short side has less white pixels next to it, then extend the rectangle in that direction. Something like that.

Comment: What do you think about the case with a white (or another color) keyboard. I think we can still look at it and know it's a keyboard, but it's not that easy for a program to do so.

Comment: It may be not too difficult to cook something up for any particular setup (e. g. "a white keyboard of known size under known viewing angle, lighting conditions, background etc.") What would probably be really difficult (if at all possible) is to do it for a more general case (e. g. "a keyboard of _any_ color, _any_ size, under _any_ angle, etc.", the more of those _"any"_ you want, the more difficult it gets).